# Adding a ViewControllers's view as subView

Tags: iphone, ios, viewcontroller

I am adding a ViewControllers view as a subView to another ViewController,

Example :

In FirstScreen viewcontroller i do this,

```
         [self.view addSubview:self.secondScreen.view];
```

And Once i remove it from FirstScreen i do this

```
         [self.secondScreen.view removeFromSuperView];
          self.secondScreen=nil;
```

But While Adding the subView **ViewDidLoad** method is called but while removeFromSuperView **ViewDidUnLoad** is not called.

My Question

1) will all my objects in my secondScreen will get deallocated once i set the instance self.secondScreen to nil

2)Is it safe to do like this so that i wont get any leaks or memory warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your app supports from iOS 5.0 onwards, you need to add it as,

```
[self addChildViewController:self.secondScreen];
[self.view addSubview:self.secondScreen.view];
```

Similarly for removing you can use `removeFromParentViewController` and then remove from superview. Check [apple documentation here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController%3a)

`ViewDidUnLoad` is deprecated from iOS 6.0 onwards and will not get called. Check [the documentation here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload)

Regarding your questions,

> 1) will all my objects in my secondScreen will get deallocated once i
>   set the instance self.secondScreen to nil

Once you are done with `self.secondScreen` class, it will start releasing objects inside this class once you set it to nil. If you are using ARC, you dont have to worry much about releasing. OS will take care of those things.

> 2)Is it safe to do like this so that i wont get any leaks or memory
>   warning

Yes, this is fine if you are using ARC. For non-ARC, you need to make sure that you have released all variables properly in this class. Make sure the retain/release are all balanced in that case.

Comment: See WWDC 2011 session 102 "Implementing UIViewController containment" around minute 16. You should not use these methods on controllers that you did not implement because they have then children they did not expect.

Danger: "This method is only intended to be called by an implementation of a custom container view controller"

Answer (score 0):

ViewDidUnload isn't called when a view is removed from a ViewController, it is called when the view is unloaded from memory. The iOS documentation about this has the following caveat:

> Called when the controller’s view is released from memory. 
>   (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged under low-memory
>   conditions and so this method is never called.)

Note the "deprecated" and the fact that "this method is never called".