# UIImageView Won't Show When ViewController Added As Subview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, subview

My main aim is to have one background for ***all of my `ViewControllers`***.  Every `ViewController` I have has a clear background.

To do this, I have made one `UIViewController` (called `backgroundViewController`) that will act as the `subview` to all my other `ViewControllers`.  It has one `UIImageView` which displays this particular background.  I will then add this `backgroundViewController` as a `subview` of all my other `ViewControllers`.

The problem is - this `imageView` won't show as a subview!

This is how I display the `imageView`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    if ([musicPlayer playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped) {

        UIImage *artworkBackgroundView;

        artworkBackgroundView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noArtworkBackground"];

        UIImage *effectImage = nil;

        backgroundView.image = effectImage;

        [backgroundView setImage:artworkBackgroundView];
        backgroundView.image = effectImage;
    }
}

- (void) handle_NowPlayingItemChanged: (id) notification
{

    if ([musicPlayer playbackState] != MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped) {

// Get artwork for current now playing item
        MPMediaItem *currentItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];

        MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [currentItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

        UIImage *artworkBackgroundView = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake(618, 618)];

        if (!artworkImage) {
            artworkBackgroundView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noArtworkBackground"];
            artworkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noArtwork"];
        }

        [backgroundView setImage:artworkBackgroundView];            
    }
}
```

As you can see, `backgroundView` changes each time the music player skips song.

To test that `backgroundViewController` does show as a subview, I added another imageView and changed its image to a static .png in Interface Builder, *and that shows correctly as a subview*.

**This is how I make it a subview for other `ViewControllers`:**

```
backgroundViewController *backgroundVC = [[backgroundViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"backgroundViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view insertSubview:backgroundVC.view atIndex:0];
```

What I want is the `UIImageView` called `backgroundView` to show up when it is being called as subview.

I have tested that `backgroundView` does change according to what song is playing, and it works correctly.

What am I doing wrong?  `backgroundView` refuses to show up as a `subview`?!  I've searched a ton about adding `ViewControllers` as `subviews` but I can't find a similar problem.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!  :)

Comment: How is your backgroundVC and backgroundView connected? Instead of using a VC for background use just an image view.

Comment: @NaveenPrasadR How would I do this?  I have never subclassed UIImageView and I have read that it is bad practice to do so - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719409/creating-subclass-of-uiimageview

Comment: Why you need a backgroundVC for background? Why not just UIImageView? You need not subclass an image view, just instantiate and add it to your view controllers instead of instantiating a BackGroundViewController?

Comment: @NaveenPrasadR , how would I do this?  I have never done this before :S

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
backgroundViewController *backgroundVC = [[backgroundViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"backgroundViewController" bundle:nil];

[self addChildViewController:backgroundVC];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundVC.view];
```

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13797107/3127576).  I need to read more about 'Custom Containers'.